# React Mobx componentDidUpdate is not updating when observable changes

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I'm new to Mobx and reactjs in general, I have knowledge in Redux and react native, and in Redux when I used to call an action and the props get updated, the `componentDidUpdate` life cycle method is triggered.

The scenario I'm having now is login. so the user fills the form, clicks submit, and the submit calls a Mobx action (asynchronous), and when the server responds, an observable is updated, and then it navigates to a main page (navigation happens in the component).

Here is my store code.

```js
import { autorun, observable, action, runInAction, computed, useStrict } from 'mobx';

useStrict(true);

class LoginStore {
    @observable authenticated = false;
    @observable token = '';

    @computed get isAuthenticated() { return this.authenticated; }


    @action login = async (credentials) => {
        const res = await window.swaggerClient.Auth.login(credentials)l
        // checking response for erros
        runInAction(() => {
            this.token = res.obj.token;
            this.authenticated = true;
        });
    }
}

const store = new LoginStore();

export default store;

export { LoginStore };
```

and this handler is in my component.

```js
handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
            if (!err) {
                this.props.store.login(values);
            }
        });
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.store.isAuthenticated) {
            const cookies = new Cookies();
            cookies.set('_cookie_name', this.props.store.token);
            this.props.history.push('main');
        }
    }
```

It's not the ideal code, I'm just experimenting, but I'm not quite getting it.

Also, if I use the computed value `(isAuthenticated)` in the `render` life cycle method, the `componentDidUpdate` is triggered, but if I didn't use it in the `render` method, the `componentDidUpdate` is not triggered.
For example, if I do this

```js
render() {
  if (this.props.store.isAuthenticated) return null
  // .... rest of the code here
}
```

the above will trigger the componentDidUpdate.

Am I missing something? is there a better way to do it with Mobx?
Thanks

Comment: An observer React Component will re-render when the observables that got de-referenced in the last render are changed. Maybe it would be better to put this logic separated from the view?

Comment: @Tholle yeah definitely the logic should be separated from the view, I'm just experimenting with mobx, and I wanted to know about this case specifically. 
Thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observer component will only react to observables referred in its `render` method. MobX documentation [covers this](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react#observercomponentclass).

I would recommend you to use [`when`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/when.html) to solve the problem.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  when(
    () => this.props.store.isAuthenticated,
    () => { 
      // put your navigation logic here
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: it's the same problem, it's not triggering unless the render function has the `this.props.store` and if the render function has it, the `componentDidUpdate` is triggered. what could be wrong here?

Comment: oh thanks for the explanation, and that worked as I wanted. is `when` safe to use in production though?

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady what do you mean? We use `when` in our production code and it works as it should. I don't understand what kind of safety you are talking about.

Comment: @Alik it shows an error , when is not defined. How to import it?

Answer (score 1):

Mobx suggests the following solutions for such a case:

1. [when](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html#when)
2. [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html#autorun)
3. [reaction](https://mobx.js.org/reactions.html#reaction)

See the examples below, and don't forget to dispose:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.disposers.push(

            // option with autorun:

            autorun(() => {
                this.runYourLogicHere();
            })

            // another option with reaction:

            reaction(
                () => this.yourModelOrProps.something,
                () => {
                    this.runYourLogicHere();
                }
            )

    )
}
...

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.disposers.forEach(disposer => {
        disposer();
    });
}
```

And see [the answer of @Dominik Serafin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51688293) in parallel thread as a reference.