# How to make MobX update the component when observable is not used in the render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

After switching from Redux to MobX for React I'm starting to extremely like MobX. It's pretty awesome.

MobX has a certain behavior where it won't update component if the provided store observable is not used in render. I think generally that's a pretty great behavior that makes components render only when something actually changed.

But... I do encountered couple of cases where I do not want or need to use MobX observable inside render method and in such cases my `this.props.store` with MobX store won't get updated.

And in such cases, as a workaround, I just reference the observable in the render method, but I don't think that's a very clean approach, and I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do that?

This component code should explain even more what I'm exactly asking about.
It's a component that changes body overflow style based on a MobX observable that I have in my store.

```
/*------------------------------------*\
  Imports
\*------------------------------------*/
import React from 'react';
import connectStore from 'script/connect-store';
import addClass from 'dom-helpers/class/addClass';
import removeClass from 'dom-helpers/class/removeClass';


/*------------------------------------*\
  Component
\*------------------------------------*/
class Component extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.constructor.displayName = 'BodyClassSync';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.checkAndUpdateMuiClass();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.checkAndUpdateMuiClass();
  }

  checkAndUpdateMuiClass() {

    // This place is the only place I need latest MobX store... 
    if (this.props.store.muiOverlay) {
      addClass(window.document.body, 'mod-mui-overlay');
    }

    else {
      removeClass(window.document.body, 'mod-mui-overlay');
    }

  }


  render() {

    // This is my workaround so the componentDidUpdate will actually fire
    // (with latest and updated store)
    // when the 'muiOverlay' observable changes in the MobX store
    // Is there any cleaner/better way to do this?
    this.props.store.muiOverlay;

    // This component doesn't and shouldn't render anything
    return null;

  }



}



/*------------------------------------*\
  Export
\*------------------------------------*/
const ComponentWithStore = connectStore(Component);
export default ComponentWithStore;
```

(Note: I don't use @decorators, I connect store using ES5 syntax in the connectStore function. And it would be awesome if solution to this would be also in ES5.)

Comment: @tholle, out of curiosity what was the intention behind editing my code example from single to double quotation marks and also changing the indentation in the comment headers?

Comment: I apologize. I read it wrong and thought there were some formatting errors. I reverted it.

Comment: @Tholle ahh no problem. The #javascript tag is welcome addition though, thanks!

Comment: You are checking for `this.props.store.muiOverlay` in `checkAndUpdateMuiClass `. Can it be set to an empty string outside of this component?

Comment: @Tholle in case of this exact component and `muiOverlay` observable - the value of that observable is always boolean

Comment: Did you find another solution for this?

Comment: Hey @Tholle, yes I found another solution. But it's pretty similar to your solution. I'll add it soon as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure how I missed it, but thanks to @Tholle I've reread the "Reacting to observables" section in the MobX docs and found out the `reaction` helper was the most suitable solution for me.

While, the `reaction` was the most fitting for the exact problem I had. The `autorun` and `when` helpers are pretty similar in the function and I probably could use them for my use case too.

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/when.html

https://mobx.js.org/refguide/reaction.html

---

This is the code example that shows how to use `reaction` for anyone that just wants quick copy+paste:

```
componentDidMount(){
  this._notificationsReactionDispose = mobx.reaction(
    () => this.props.store.notifications,
    (notifications, reaction) => {
      ... the code that runs when "notifications" in my store change
    }
  );
}

componentWillUnmount() {
  this._notificationsReactionDispose();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [autorun](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) in `componentDidMount` and dispose the listener in `componentWillUnmount` so that you don't have to reference it in the render method.

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.constructor.displayName = 'BodyClassSync';
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dispose = autorun(() => {
      const { muiOverlay } = this.props.store;

      if (muiOverlay) {
        addClass(window.document.body, 'mod-mui-overlay');
      } else {
        removeClass(window.document.body, 'mod-mui-overlay');
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.dispose();
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Since you are not really doing anything in this component, you could put this `autorun` directly in your store as well.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I've upvoted this answer and will probably use this method for some of my other components where I use greater amount of MobX observables. But... I'm still wondering if there's any other way to do this? This still seems a little hackish because from my understanding of autorun it will update on every store change - not only in this case `muiOverlay` observable.

Comment: `autorun` will only run again when the observables it referenced last time are changed, i.e. *only* when `muiOverlay` changes.

Comment: So if I in this case reference only `muiOverlay` inside the autorun function, then that function will get executed **only** if the `muiOverlay` changes? And if other observables of `this.props.store` change, then the autorun function won't execute at all?

Comment: @DominikSerafin That's right. [Look at this for a basic example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jjwo7w3w25).

Comment: Thanks for explanation and the example, I appreciate that

Comment: Thanks for the example! Do you think it will harm the performance if I'm going to use `autorun` in multiple components? Is there a better solution?